# Iterate through 3 rows at once in Python 3 using itertools()

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, python-itertools

This piece of code helps to iterate through 2 rows at once.
How can we iterate through 3 rows at once in a dataframe in pandas?

For example

1,2,3

2,3,4

3,4,5
etc

```
from itertools import tee
from itertools import zip_longest as izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

for (idx1, row1), (idx2, row2) in pairwise(stock_fut.iterrows()):
    print(idx1,row1,"\n\n",idx2,row2,"\n\n")
```

Comment: `tee` defaults 2, try `a, b, c = tee(iterable, 3)`

Comment: What about rolling windows?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
from itertools import tee
from itertools import zip_longest as izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b, c = tee(iterable,3)
    next(b);next(c);next(c)
    return izip(a, b, c)

for (idx1, row1), (idx2, row2), (idx3, row3) in pairwise(stock_fut.iterrows()):
    print(idx1,row1,"\n\n",idx2,row2,"\n\n",idx3, row3,"\n\n")
```